# ValueError: too many values to unpack while parsing the txt

Tags: python, parsing, replace

I have a small txt file, where I need to replace the multiple spaces with single tab on the lines that begin with specific keyword, so for that firstly I replace the multiple spaces with single one, that will be then replaced by tab
My script:

```
input_file=open('file.txt', "rw")
for i, line in input_file:
    if line.startswith('City'):
        while '  ' in line:
            line = line.replace('  ', ' ')
        input_file.write(line)
input_file.close
```

and I have this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-dfd976cfc18d> in <module>()
      1 input_file=open('file.txt', "rw")
----> 2 for i, line in input_file:
      3     if line.startswith('City'):
      4         while '  ' in line:
      5             line = line.replace('  ', ' ')

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Why it could happen?

Comment: It should be `for line in input_file:` You don't use `i` anywhere so I don't know what you expect it to be, but if you want it to count the lines as you go, it should be `for i, line in enumerate(input_file)`.

Comment: See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12586508/4116239) to a slightly different question for details of what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need `i`, which is a number (starting from 0 if `start` keyword argument is not defined) that increments on each iteration and generated by `enumerate` :

Try adding [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
```

If you don't, just use:

```
for line in input_file:
```

---

Regarding "double white-space deletion", there is no need to use **`while`**. Just use `if` and `replace`:

```
if '  ' in line:
    line = line.replace('  ', ' ')
input_file.write(line)
```

---

Regarding **`open()`**, you can avoid closing the opened file by using **`with`** statement.

> This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its
>   suite finishes

```
with open('file.txt', "rw") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.startswith('City'):
            if '  ' in line:
                line = line.replace('  ', ' ')
            input_file.write(line)
```

See the last example of this section https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

---

Change **`open()`** mode from `"rw"` to `"r+"`, to avoid the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: @tdelaney thank you! I've updated my answer and learned something today.

Comment: @bmhkim I understand your POV, but I won't kill myself writing an answer to a person that isn't killing himself searching. This is really basic Python, he must read before asking and there are a lot of questions and tutorials about how does `for` works. I'm just presenting him `enumerate` so he can search what it does and how it helps.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH.: No problem :D

Comment: By the way, really need it? Looks like OP never used that `i` so what about  simply `for line in input_file:`?

Comment: Also I'd suggest OP use `if '  ' in line:` instead of `while '  ' in line:`.

Comment: @KevinGuan I've updated my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KevinGuan I use ```while '  ' in line``` because I found it appropriate in the case when I haven't idea where and how many whitespaces I have in each line, but why you think ```if``` statement will be better?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I don't know if it's works because in both cases , ```for i, line in enumerate(input_file)``` or ```for line in input_file```  it now throws out ```IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor``` , so i'm trying to find out why

Comment: @very_young try changing the open mode from `open('file.txt', "rw")` to `open('file.txt', "r+")` and let me know if it works so I can update my answer.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. thanks for answer but just to clarify the things: it's not because I'm lazy or stupid that I ask the question but because I was looking for an answer in different ways, and I haven't found, I read a lot before asking. sorry, but I'm beginner, and maybe my question is very easy, but even if it's basic and you think, it's dirty work for you to explain so easy basic things in details, it's OK (actually I'm already happy with an answer that gives me a hint! ), please, make attention in your comments about other users.

Comment: @very_young: Because [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replace all character in a string unless you set `count`, for example `'foo'.replace('o', 'a')` return `'faa'`. Actually you can simply run `str.replace()` without `while` or `if`. If there's nothing can replace `str.replace()` will return the original string and doesn't raise an error. Check the document that I linked for more details.

Comment: @very_young This has nothing to do with being a beginner or a ninja, it's just a matter of reading and researching. People won't help much if you post a question that shows a lack of research. I haven't insulted you neither ignored you, I have helped you. I just shared my thoughts/opinions which you must respect.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. and I very grateful to you for your help! as I said, your answer was very good for me, but I think, judging an answer as 'lack of research' has smth to do with being beginner or ninja. Being beginner, I often choose not the right terms to search for, and so, if you are a ninja, you already know (or at least guess), where is the problem and what you are looking for, that make your research more easy, quickly and efficient. and I think the goal of SO is to help beginners to become ninja faster than would become without SO just by making research themselves.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. now with ```open('file.txt', "r+")``` it works!

Comment: @very_young I've updated my answer, you can set it as your question's answer if you consider it. Let's leave our discussion there, and apologize me if you felt bad vibes from my side. Just take my words as a suggestion for your future questions. Have a nice weekend.